# Webpage communicating with /triggering event on C# program?

Tags: c#, php, javascript, http, tcp

I'm planning on creating a C# program (an IRC bot, to be specific).  I need it to be able to receive requests from and/or be controlled by a web page.  I plan on getting a VPS, that I will host my website and this bot on.

For example, suppose I have a button on an ajax page.  If a user clicks that button, could it trigger a c# event using php, and perhaps carry some arguments (like text in a form on that same page)?

I am new to this field of programming and may not use some correct terminology, and feel free to correct me.

Comment: I am sure there are people here with lots and lots of ideas. You need to ask a more specific question. What have you done already? What are your ideas?

Comment: I'm clarifying the question now.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to be using `TcpClient`. [System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx)

Comment: Good idea, I really don't know much about tcp.  It's always been a shady area of programming for me, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: I edited the question, I don't know if communicating over the internet via tcp is the right thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

Boom baby!  IRC bot code is he'ya:
[IRC Bot code](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/pasihavia/IrcBot11222005231107PM/IrcBot.aspx)

And while there are a hundred ways to sunday to make a program that responds to http requests, go do a tutorial on **Asp.Net**.  Whether it's taking a command through a web page or showing an interface, this will be a nice step into an easy new technology for you:

http://www.asp.net/mvc

In particular, go through the free PluralSight training on that web page.  You will not regret it.

Comment: Thanks for the bot code, that will help get me on the rihgt track.